# Docker fails with error inside debian vagrant box

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile, cgroups, debian-jessie

Inside a Vagrant box with **Docker version 17.11.0-ce build 1caf76c**, this docker command fails:

```
docker run mongo:3.4 -v /home/vagrant/src/db:/db -p 27017:27017 --name mongo
```

with the following error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: cgroups: memory cgroup not supported on this system: unknown.
ERRO[0027] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

OS:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie)
Release:    8.9
Codename:   jessie
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this? It worked with an jessie box not older than a few weeks before.

Thanks :)

Comment: same message in a fresh vm using the debian:jessie, golang:latest (and may be other) docker images.
Images build successfully in a native environment

Comment: Same for me, fresh install Raspbian Stretch Lite 4.9 and Docker 17.11.0-ce.

Comment: I rolled back to 17.06 and it works now.

Comment: Rolled back to 17.09 and its working for me.

Comment: Docker `17.09` is the most recent **stable** version of Docker; so that's likely your issue.

Comment: @TJBiddle Vagrant uses get.docker.com script to install docker. This is advertised to ship the latest stable docker and that seems to be 17.11

Comment: @User9123 Then Vagrant is using that script incorrectly; or it's written incorrectly. The most stable release is 17.09 https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/ 17.11 shows up in "Edge Releases"